# npm kicks off msbuild and fails

Tags: node.js, npm

Trying to install various packages with npm on a Windows machine, for example

```
npm install node-stringprep
```

I often run into this error message:

```
Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
```

So it looks like it's trying to build some source files and fails to do so.

Is there a recommended way to set up my environment so npm can successfully install those type of packages (which build source files)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like running in Visual Studio Command Prompt and adding the following switch helps:

```
npm install node-stringprep --msvs_version=2012
```